# Difficulty with using HTML DOM .createElement(), .setAttributeNode(), and .appendChild() methods

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm learning how to develop a dynamic webpage and am trying to use HTML DOM to add JS objects but nothing is appearing after several troubleshooting attempts.

I've tried using .createAttribute() instead of .setAttribute() and have carefully read the descriptions of all the methods to make sure I was using them correctly.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="greeting_section">
        </div>
    <script>
        let greeting_post = document.createElement("P");
        greeting_post = document.setAttributeNode("id","post");
        let greeting_post_text = document.createTextNode("howdy howdy");
        greeting_post.appendChild(greeting_post_text);
        document.getElementById("greeting_section").appendChild(greeting_post);        
    </script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect it to output "howdy howdy" but nothing appears in my Firefox browser.

Comment: "_nothing appears_" Something will appear, see the DevConsole: "_TypeError: document.setAttributeNode is not a function_". Only elements have the said property, it's not included in `document`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're overwriting `greeting_post`. Also, you might just be meaning to use `setAttribute` instead of `setAttributeNode`. See below for a working example.

```js
let greeting_post = document.createElement("P");
greeting_post.setAttribute("id","post");
let greeting_post_text = document.createTextNode("howdy howdy");
greeting_post.appendChild(greeting_post_text);
document.getElementById("greeting_section").appendChild(greeting_post);
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="greeting_section">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First: When I ran your code the browser console showed this error

> Uncaught TypeError: document.setAttributeNode is not a function

That's the first thing you should do when your code doesn't work, Take a look at the browser console.

Second: in your code `greeting_post = document.setAttributeNode("id","post");` you are trying to add `id="post"` to `greeting_post` variable which is the p tag put you do it wrong, Your code means change the variable `greeting_post` to a new value `document.setAttributeNode("id","post");` which mean **Set attribute id="post" to the document**.
So, instead of your code, The correct code should go like this:

```js
greeting_post.setAttribute("id","post");
```

In English this is mean, select `greeting_post` and set it's attribute to `id="post"`

So finale, The complete code should be like this:

```js
let greeting_post = document.createElement("P"),
    greeting_post_text = document.createTextNode("howdy howdy");

greeting_post.setAttribute("id","post");
greeting_post.appendChild(greeting_post_text);
document.getElementById("greeting_section").appendChild(greeting_post);
```